# Add own custom method to an existing library

Tags: java

Consider logging libraries like logdj, slf4j etc. They have methods like `log.info('')`. Let's say I want to add my own custom method on top of this library so that I can use it something like

`log.audit('')`

What is the best way to add such kind of custom method to existing library?

Comment: If whatever class `log` is is not final you could inherit from it, add your method and use your custom class in place of the existing one. Or you could do the non-confusing thing and make your own class completely decoupled from the original one.

Comment: Do you have some example?

Comment: You want an example of inheriting from a class and adding a method?

Comment: Use kotlin? Java doesn't have extension methods so you'll have to subclass or compose, as frederico commented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about logging libraries in particular and adding method like `log.audit('')` this means that you want to add another logging level in addition to trace, debug, info warn and so on. This would be very complex change which I wouldn't recommend writing. But in general if you are talking about any Open source library available on Github you can always create your own branch or clone it and make any changes/additions you like. If the source code not available than you can just extend the class and write your own functionality there

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't need to modify libraries. Check the documentation. For example, Log4j2 supports [custom log levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) or [markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html).